# Python Pivot Rows into Columns Group by Max

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm fairly new with Python and pandas and have a problem I'm not quite sure how to solve. I have a pandas DataFrame that contains hockey players who have played for multiple teams in the same year:

```
Player         Season      Team      GP        G      A       TP      
Player A        2020        A        10        8      3       11
Player A        2020        B        25        10     5       15
```

I want to be able to combine rows that contain the same player from the same year, and arrange the columns by the team that player played the most for. In the above example all of Team B's numbers would be first because Player A has played the most games for Team B.

For example the df above would turn into (HTeam stands for highest team):

```
Player        Season      HTeam      HGP    HG      HA     HTP     LTeam      LGP        LG      LA       LTP
Player A      2020          B        25     10      5      15       A         10         8       3        11
```

The initial way I can think of attacking this problem is by using a series of groupby max but I'm not sure if that will achieve the desired outcome. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this:

```
#For one season determine which of two records has the most games played
#This logic can use something like pd.cut for more that two teams in a season
df['H/L'] = np.where(df['GP'] < df.groupby(['Player', 'Season'])['GP'].transform('max') ,'L','H')

#Reshape the dataframe using indexes and unstack
a = df.set_index(['Player','Season','H/L']).unstack()

#Flatten multiindex header created by reshaping
a.columns = [f'{j}{i}' for i,j in a.columns]

#sort and move indexes back into the dataframe columns
a = a.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
  Player  Season  HA  HG  HGP  HTP HTeam  LA  LG  LGP  LTP LTeam
0      A    2020   1  10   25   15     B   3   8   10   11     A
```

Answer (score 2):

`sort` then `groupby` + `head/tail` and combine the results. If a player has only 1 entry it will be considered both `H` and `L` so you could filter those out before if necessary.

```
df = df.sort_values('GP')

gps = ['Player', 'Season']
pd.concat([df.groupby(gps).tail(1).set_index(gps).add_prefix('H'), 
           df.groupby(gps).head(1).set_index(gps).add_prefix('L')], axis=1)

#               HTeam  HGP  HG  HA  HTP LTeam  LGP  LG  LA  LTP
#Player  Season                                                
#PlayerA 2020       B   25  10   5   15     A   10   8   3   11
```